# NonUniqueResult but actually one row

Tags: sql, hibernate

Ii have an issue with `uniqueResult()`.

I have this piece of code

```
SQLQuery query = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).createSQLQuery(strQuery.toString());

Entity result = (Entity ) query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Entity .class)).uniqueResult();
```

Sorry for the little information but it's code that I cannot show for policy reasons.

I executed the query that fails from the log with the correct parameter and returns only one result.

So the question would be:

How does `query.uniqueResult()` throws that exception but the same query on the same database performed manually returns a single row?

It's a select

Thanks

Davide

**UPDATE**

```
2018-10-01 14:34:00,386 INFO  [it.**] (default task-18) method=**, params= [1324680], time=31ms
2018-10-01 14:34:00,386 INFO  [it.**] (default task-18) method=** START
2018-10-01 14:34:00,411 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) Hibernate:  SELECT .... WHERE table.field = ?                                                                                                                                       

2018-10-01 14:34:00,436 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-18) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component ** for method public it.** it.**.processData(it.**): javax.ejb.EJBException: org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2
    at ****
    ...
    ...
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2
```

I have hidden some names, but here's the query that fail. I passed the parameter 1324680 to the query that failed and returned on the same database only one result.

Comment: What exception you are getting ?

Comment: NonUniqueResultException. Thanks

Comment: I highly doubt this is a hibernate bug so a couple things to check: are you absolutely sure you are running the same query?  you mention a parameter, but your example shows no parameter being set.  Are you sure that you are manually running you query on the same database that the application is utilizing?